How do I write tests for my django-extensions cron job?
I have a cron job in my Django app that's defined as a MinutelyJob (from django-extensions).
How do I write tests for the job?  The module documentation is quite sparse, and doesn't tell me how to call the job from code as opposed to the command line.  I don't want to write test code that depends on undocumented interfaces.
Alternatively, should I reimplement the job using a different module?  I only have the one job so Celery is a bit heavyweight for my use case.
